# Contour-line looking artifact on diffuse irradiance map

Tags: pbr, diffuse, ibl

I tried implementing my own diffuse irradiance map maker after reading [Learn OpenGL > PBR > IBL > Diffuse Irradiance](https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Diffuse-irradiance).

It takes an HDR image and makes six HDR cube map.
But It keeps making this very bright dots that altogether forms some kind of contour lines. (Almost looks like gamma correction artifact)

Any idea what possibly can cause this kind of artifacts?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most likely you are undersampling, and the bright spots occur when one of your samples happens to land on the sun.

Comment: @NathanReed You were right I was indeed undersampling. I’ll try more-sampling and see how it go.

Comment: @NathanReed I tried more-sampling but the bright-dot problem persists. They just get little more blurry.

Comment: I guess the samples that hits the sun are not properly weighted. I’m going to look into that part.

Comment: Double check your sampling pattern and make sure you're getting well distributed samples as you increase the number? You could also try scaling down the input HDRI, so that you don't need so many samples when building the diffuse maps.

Comment: I was following Learn OpenGL's PBR-Diffuse Irradiance chapter and turns out they were converting HDR into LDR before the sampling. I must have missed that step.

Comment: But I still don't understand. Why would they use LDR environment in PBR rendering?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Can you point to where they're doing that in the article?

Comment: @NathanReed Nevermind, I was wrong. They turn HDR into LDR only when they are rendering the skybox. 

Comment: @NathanReed Also the same problem is addressed in the comment section and they say it's because the HDR image I'm using has abnormally high value by, for example, directly catching the sun, which is indeed my case.

Comment: @NathanReed And I just realized you pointed out it in the first comment months ago. I could have solved it much earlier if I had listened!